# Different log in levels

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication

I currently have a project where I need to have different access options for different users. Also these users are in teams which have specific data.

The proposed architecture was:

step 1: User logs in.

step 2: User creates a team(becomes team leader), join a team or select existing teams linked to profile.

step 3: Display data based on team selected, and user privileges on that team.

step 4: User is able to select a different active team and display it's data.

For user authentication I was using "Session" library[1](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), but for these two levels of user login + team selection, adding everything to the current session doesn't look like the best way to do things. Is there any best practice case?

Solution used so far:

```
    $loggedInTeam = array(
        'id' => $data['team']->id,
        'name' => $data['team']->name,
        'leader' => $data['team']->leader,
        'points' => $data['team']->points,
        'image' => $data['team']->image
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata('equipe', $loggedInTeam);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book**, **tool**, **software library**, **tutorial** or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sorry if the question was poorly formulated, the problem is having different level of log in/selection, with custom functionalities for these log in/selections, as for what was done so far to solve it, I was using the "session" library, as described in the question. It provides some authentication, but not for multiple options, as far as I could get. @PedroLobito

Comment: for this kind of functionality it would be better to use Roles for each user and team access permission per user which is just another permission table to track access between team<->user